# Baseline downshift when pasting object in first line of textframe in Adobe InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, margin

I need to set up аn empty space around inline icon in Indesign. Something like margins in HTML. Their sizes will not depend on an icon size. Also I think of negative margins. Also, I can't move inline (anchored) object outside upper boundary of textframe without baseline shift.

Solutions?

Here is the problem:

[image]

Still no luck! It seems to me I have explored everything both in Text Wrap panel and in Anchored Object Options menu.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can make the **`Bad baseline downshift`** choice, then select the text frame and press `cmd+b`, in the second panel choose `fixed` and change the measure in box (if you have `preview` activate you can see direct the result).
Wrong:

[image]

Right:
[image]

English interface:
[image]

Comment: You're welcome, thank you for english version ;)